I'm Getting "error processing request body error domain=nsurlerror -1000"
I'm developing a React Native application and encountering an issue when making a POST request on iOS. The error message I receive is:
error processing request body error domain=nsurlerror -1000

Heres the error
I use react native 0.73.7. And my API url is correct.
Here is my code:
const onClickPost = async ()  => {
setApiCall(true);
    let data = {
        price: price,
        registrationPrice: registrationPrice,
        brand: make,
        postType: 'SELL',
        modelYear: year,
        carType: bodyType,
        mileAge: mileage,
        fuel: fuel,
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('model', JSON.stringify(data));

    imageUri.forEach((uri, index) => {
            formData.append('file', {
                uri: uri,
                name: `photo_${index}.jpg`,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
            });
    });

    console.log("im here");

        createOffer(formData).then(() => {
            setApiCall(false);
            createSuccessAlert();
        }).catch(e => {

            setApiCall(false);
            createFailAlert()
            console.log('error');
            console.log(e);
            throw e;
        });
    console.log("im here as well"); 
}


Check your url. Url is most likely malformed.

The error you're getting is likely due to the way you're constructing and sending the FormData in your POST request.
In React Native, when sending a FormData object in a POST request, you need to specify the contentType header as multipart/form-data in your request options. This tells the server that the request body contains a mixture of text and binary data.
Here's an example of how you can modify your createOffer function to include the necessary headers:
import axios from 'axios';
const createOffer = async (formData) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://your-api-url.com/', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    });
    const responseData = response.data;
    return responseData;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};


chatgpt response.

Who the hell you are & why you saying that @emrevarol
